# short tags doesn`t work despite i have changed short_open_tag = On (i have mac os x)

Tags: php, apache2

php.ini :

```
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

Comment: That's nice. There probably is an easy fix to this. Someone you've missed. Check it all again

Comment: You do realise that a `;` is a comment marker and those lines at the top of the file are just for information. Look lower down in `php.ini` for the actual `short_open_tag` parameter

Comment: and restart your web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look something like below:

```
; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It is
; generally recommended that <?php and ?> should be used and that this feature
; should be disabled, as enabling it may result in issues when generating XML
; documents, however this remains supported for backward compatibility reasons.
; Note that this directive does not control the <?= shorthand tag, which can be
; used regardless of this directive.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = Off
```

Below is just a comment :

```
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

Also restart web server after updation.

Answer (score 0):

add to php.ini

> short_open_tag = On[image]

Then restart the server, for more information look at the screenshot attached.

Thanks
Amit